# Just updated boto3, don't have functionality listed in the docs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get information from my vpc endpoint service with methods like 'describe_vpc_endpoint_service_configurations()'.
However, I am getting the message that this attribute doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

```
    >>> boto3.__version__
    '1.7.81'
    >>> botocore.__version__
    '1.10.81'
    >>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
    >>> ec2.describe_vpc_endpoint_connection_notifications()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Users/erinmc/.virtualenvs/networking-gameday-2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 555, in __getattr__
self.__class__.__name__, item)
    AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'describe_vpc_endpoint_connection_notifications'
    >>> ec2.describe_vpc_endpoint_service_configurations()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Users/erinmc/.virtualenvs/networking-gameday-2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 555, in __getattr__
self.__class__.__name__, item)
    AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'describe_vpc_endpoint_service_configurations'
```

Comment: Odd, I can't replicate on Python 2 or 3 with the code and versions you indicated above.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. Start a new virtualenv and try again. Maybe your current virtualenv is broken for boto3.

Comment: Strange, I created a new virtual environment and get the same thing. I even installed on my machine outside of the virtual environment and get the same error. Is there something outside of boto3 or botocore that it requires?